# Can PCIe Gen 3.0 / x 4 bottleneck my GPU?

Tags: pci-express, gaming

My motherboard has PCIe v3.0 / x 4.

My GPU is a 2080 Super.

I have a 27 inch 1440p monitor

Comment: Inmost cases PCI-e v3 x4 is enough for most graphics cards. In you case I expect about a 6% speed loss in high high in with high settings. This has already been answered in much more details and much more generic in this site.  The generic part is importnat since hardware/software specs question or very prcise HW (which in a year will be outdated) question are considered off topic.  Hence the close vote which it already has attracted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a four-lane PCIe drive will not generate a bottleneck for a Graphics Processing Unit.